# What does the nginx 502 559 error code mean?

Tags: nginx, bad-gateway

I'm getting a "502 559" error in my nginx error logs.  I know that the 502 means "bad gateway".  What does the 559 mean?

Comment: In the default [`access_log` format](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) the `$body_bytes_sent` follows the `$status`. So that's the number of bytes in the HTML response that Nginx sent to the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Richard Smith in the comment, `559` in the nginx log stands for:

> the number of bytes in the HTML response that Nginx sent to the browser

Source:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format

or, as specified in the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_body_bytes_sent):

> `$body_bytes_sent`
> **number of bytes sent to a client, not counting the response header**; this variable is compatible with the `“%B”` parameter of the `mod_log_config` Apache module